# NHibernate disable id generator for bulk operation

Tags: nhibernate, bulkinsert

I have to bulk import data into my database using nhibernate and my mapped model.
I set up a guid.comb generator for ids.
Is there's a way to import data with yet assigned ids disabling temporary guid.comb id generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can temporarily change the id generator to assigned. Then, after import is finished switch it back to COMB Guids. Just be sure you explicitly call session.Save() instead of SaveOrUpdate(). Does that solve your problem?

Comment: If you're going to be doing bulk imports frequently (rather than just a one-time operation), you can modify the Configuration object in memory to change the id to Assigned before building your SessionFactory. This way you don't have to maintain two sets of hbm.xml files. I discussed a similar technique (for temporarily making lookup tables updatable) in this blog post: http://jameskovacs.com/2007/11/04/testing-immutable-entities-with-nhibernate/

Comment: hey James many thanks, your solution seems to be the solution. Just one question: The "Id generator" disabling could be made for cascading entities? thanks a lot. P.s. how can I set your suggestion as the real answer of my question? thanks

Comment: Filip this could be a good idea to change the id, but I was asking how to do that, and to make bulk operation is not suggested to use the standard session, but instead it's needed to use the Stateless Session to do bulk operations for many reasons. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hoghweed: didn't take the "bulk" part of your question into account. Yes, bulk operations should be processed using stateless session.